# Help in this transistor level ciruit

Tags: circuitikz, circuits

I'm working in this circuit:

[image]

Here what I have done:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages, european resistors]
\ctikzset { label/align = straight }
\draw (0,0) 
node[nmos](nmosA){}node[left=10mm] {$\overline{A}$} (2,0)
node[nmos](nmosB){}node[left=10mm] {B}
(nmosA.D) to (nmosB.D)
to [short,*-o] ++(1,0) {} node[right=2mm] {Y}
(1,-1.54) node[nmos](nmosC){}node[left=10mm] {C}
(nmosA.S) to (nmosC.D) to (nmosB.S);
%(nmosC.S) to node[ground]{};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd like to know how to connect the ground (the way I tried is wrong), how to put circles in the opened terminals of the transistors and maybe how to improve the draw since I put some weird coordinates `(1,-1.54) node[nmos](nmosC){}node[left=10mm]`. If someone has a similar example would be of great value.
Regards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how I would do it. Instead of manually adjusting the position of the labels, use the anchors of the transistors and position the label nodes left or right of these. `to` paths leading nowhere (`++(0,0)`) can be used to add filled or open marks at the transistor anchors.

I also avoided manually positioning the transistor "C" by using the `calc` library to compute the midpoint and anchoring the final transistor by its drain.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\ctikzset { label/align = straight }

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages, european resistors]
\draw (0,0) 
  node[nmos] (nmosA) {}
  (nmosA.G) to[short,-o] ++(0,0) node[left] {$\overline{A}$} (2,0)
  node[nmos] (nmosB) {}
  (nmosB.G) to[short,-o] ++(0,0) node[left] {B}
  (nmosA.D) to (nmosB.D)
  to [short,*-o] ++(1,0) {} node[right] {Y}
  (nmosA.S) to[short] (nmosB.S)
  ($(nmosA.S)!0.5!(nmosB.S)$) to[short,-*] ++(0,0) node[nmos,anchor=D] (nmosC) {}
  (nmosC.G) to[short,-o] ++(0,0) node[left] {C}
  (nmosC.S) node[ground] {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of using the `calc` library, it should be possible to do `(nmosA.S) to[short] coordinate[midway] (tmp) (nmosB.S)` and use the coordinate `tmp` as the anchor for transistor "C", but for some reason this did not place the `tmp` coordinate at the spot I expected it to. I'll look into it more when I have some moments.